# Bootstrap 3 what cause the blank space on small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

Does anybody knows why I get blank space on right side when I shrink browser to small and extra small screen?

Image : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jawcxtubfgdv48u/gap.png?dl=0

I use MVC4 + bootstrap and my custom css.

```html
//layout.cshtml:
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @RenderBody() 
  </div>
   </div>

//index.cshtml:


@section featured {
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Events.</h2>
          
        </div>
    </div>
}
<!-- Example row of columns -->
<div class="row">
    <div id="catListings" class="mainWrap clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12">                         
            <div class="sorting clearfix">
                <div class="totalItems">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>@Model.TotalItemCount    
                </div>
                <div class="vfilters">
                    <div class="vlabel" style="float: left;">Sort</div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dvCategoryResults" style="display: none">
           
            <table class="table listings">
                <tbody>               
                        @Html.Partial("_Event", @Model)                                                          
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
          

            <div class="text-center">
                <ul class="clearfix pagination">
                    Stran @(Model.dogodki.PageCount < Model.dogodki.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.dogodki.PageNumber) od @Model.dogodki.PageCount</>
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.dogodki, page => Url.Action("GetSortedDogodki",  new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort }))                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is caused from NOT using a container wrapper. Try adding either the `.container` class or `.container-fluid` around all sections and you're problem should disappear.

If this does not solve your issue, please post a link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your styles. But as I see from the screenshot, it might be a problem with padding or margin on your mainWrap container.

Answer (score 0):

I added div around row and the problem is solved but I dont understand why because I have .container defined in master page and all pages are rendered inside this layout.cshtml.

```html
//layout.cshtml:
<div class="container"> // Container for all pages
        <div class="row">
            @RenderBody() //I render all sites inside container
  </div>
   </div>

//index.cshtml:


@section featured {
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Events.</h2>
          
        </div>
    </div>
}
<!-- Example row of columns -->
   <div class="container"> //this has fixed the problem
<div class="row">
  
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The .container & .container-fluid classes add padding to the left and right of 15px which is used to offset the right and left negative margins (-15px) applied to the rows contained within the container.